# makemigrations - No changes detected - Django 4.2 only

Tags: django, django-models, migrate, makemigrations

Well, I was folloging Django Girls Tutorial but using django version 4.2
All was right until I need makemigrations when I created the model.

I put the new app "blog" on INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'blog',
    ]
```

Also, I don't think is necessary, but added the register on admin.py:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    
    from .models import Post
    
    admin.site.register(Post)
```

After adding all this content and installation, I need to execute makemigrations to generate the 0001_initial.py file migration inside ./blog/migrations directory, but it says me the following message:

`No changes detected`

Included the name of my app after the makemigrations command, and still changes were not detected

I searched this error on internet and tried different migrate variations, but the only one that worked for me was the next one>

`./manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Then it worked, I'm using the default django SGDB sqlite3, the database tables were created after this command and after running the server I can use the models as normal.

The problem of doing this comes when I want to edit the models, I execute makemigrations and it still doesn't detect changes. The previous command --run-syncdb only works for creating the database but cannot update with the new models fields.

I can tell the problem is from Django 4.2 because I followed the same exact steps on three different computers with Ubuntu, Termux and Windows each one.

Also I tried the same tutorial with Django 3.2 and had not any problems on migrations or database creation.

Comment: I am using Django 4.2 and face no such issue. Can you show a sample of your `models.py` class to check if there is anything wrong / different there?

Comment: I'll post my model on the question content soon

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
python manage.py makemigrations APPNAME
```

Like this :

```
python manage.py makemigrations blog
```